# Log implications of copying data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server

I need to move 10's of millions of rows from one table to another. Are there different ways I can do this that will minimize impact on log files? Clients sometimes choose Simple Recovery over the default Full. But even with simple recovery, bulk copy operations seem to consume huge amounts of log space. We can suggest a different recovery model if that will help.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (<columns>)
SELECT <columns>
FROM Table1
WHERE <condition>;

DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE <condition>;

COMMIT;
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you are moving more than 50% of the rows in a table, consider using `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`, then move the rows you want to *keep* into the new table.

Answer (score 2):

Even with Simple Recovery Model, you still have to log every part of the insert in case it fails and you need to rollback. If you are moving all of the rows (or almost all of them) as a one off process you may be better off just renaming the table and then altering the columns to be what you need.

If this is a process that runs over and over again (E.g. an end of month process) then you might want to look at [partition switching](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/sqlskills-sql101-partitioning/).

If neither of those work, then you'll probably be better off batching your inserts. Michael Swart has a [good blog](http://michaeljswart.com/2012/04/modifying-tables-online-part-1-migration-strategy/) on how to do that. See also [Take Care When Scripting Batches](http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/).

Answer (score 2):

> But even with simple recovery, **bulk copy operation**s seem to consume
>   huge amounts of log space.

Your code use `INSERT`, not `SELECT INTO`.
While both of them **can be minimally logged** in `SIMPLE`/`BULK LOGGED` recovery model, there is a difference:

`SELECT INTO` is always minimally logged and `INSERT INTO` requires some additional conditions to be minimally logged.

Your code surely produce `fully logged` operation as it does not use `TABLOCK`.

But `TABLOCK` is not the only requirement, it's only enough if you are inserting into a `heap` without indexes, but if your table has clustered index, data to be inserted should be ordered and a table should be empty. Other cases are summarized here:
[image]

And here you can find
[The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The reason if the database is in SIMPLE, but the log file is growing because of ACID.

Lets assume this,

In the first phase, you are going to insert the million of records. According to SQL Server its a single transaction. So it needs to keep the log until the transaction finish.

The best way to achieve this is loading the add in chunks.

For eg, Create a loop to insert 10 000 rows first and commit. Then current loop +1 (10 001 to 20 000). This will help to keep the log file in small size.

## For Delete in Chunks

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Declaring Local variables
DECLARE @MaxLoops AS INT;
SET @MaxLoops = 1000;
DECLARE @CurrentLoop AS INT;
SET @CurrentLoop = 0
DECLARE @Targetrows int ;
SET @Targetrows = 1000000

-- Max rows to delete in one batch
DECLARE @MaxRows INT
SET @MaxRows = 10000;

WHILE @CurrentLoop < @MaxLoops
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN  
    DELETE TOP (@MaxRows)
    FROM my_table
    WHERE [ID] < @Targetrows;
COMMIT  
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:50';
    SET @CurrentLoop = @CurrentLoop + 1;
END
```